# SAR ADC - DC Input Settling

Tags: adc, oversampling

I'm looking to use a SAR ADC with 1.6MSPS, and leveraging the integrated decimation filter to improve accuracy.

I'm using [Analog's Precision ADC Tool](https://tools.analog.com/en/adcdriver/#adc=LTC2512-24&cext=3.3e-9&driver=LTC6363&frequency=20&gain=1&inputSettlingChart=2&multiplexed=false&nTab=1&oss=false&rext=30&rf=1050&sTab=1&samplingRate=1600000&showAdcVariant=false&showDriverVariant=false&sourceType=1&tab=3&thd=200&topology=1&vSupplyNeg=-1.4&vSupplyPos=6.4&vref=5&wbNoise=0) for the combination of my selected driver and ADC (link is an interactive webapp with my configuration)

[image]

The tool is displaying a warning for the driver configuration:

[image]

This struck me as odd being that it's a recommended configuration in the [LTC2512-24 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/251224fa.pdf). Increasing the filter bandwidth the warning persists until about a 20x increase but then a new one appears due to unfiltered driver noise:

[image]

This doesn't seem like a good tradeoff since the whole point of oversampling is reduce to measurement noise.

My takeaway is that for anyone interested in measuring DC or lower frequency input signals, the intent is for the user to use a reduced sample rate and consequently a reduced decimation factor. The full 1.6MSPS only makes sense for applications which care about higher frequency input signal. The maximum decimation factor offered is 32x, so an input signal bandwidth of 25kHz would be the lowest intended application for 1.6MSPS which is far enough from DC that this issue doesn't apply?

Do I have a correct understanding? What input signal frequency range beyond DC is this artifact an issue for generally?

Comment: You said `Decreasing the filter bandwidth around 10x clears this warning` - did you actually mean that or did you mean `increasing...`?

Comment: If your new BW is 27.4 MHz, then that's way above the top sampling rate and that's not goof for ADCs and high-frequency noise aliasing. I'm guessing here that maybe your original BW was way too low and that a signal might not have settled at a constant value during the AD conversion process although, it depends on any sample and hold circuit used.

Comment: @Andyaka yes thank you, fixed decreasing->increasing.

Comment: @Andyaka there doesn't appear to be a filter bandwidth that gets good noise/aliasing performance AND gets good DC input settling accuracy.

Comment: Well, numbers are useful at this point and so is the circuit diagram of the device you are using. A link to the data sheet would also help.

Comment: @Andyaka the link to the tool contains all the details of my configuration but I copied some of this into my question and added the datasheet.

Comment: Your filter value has a cut-off of 1.6 MHz - it needs to be at least half of this to gain any antialiasing effect. I suggest you use a cut-off frequency of maybe 160 kHz and try that. Do you understand what is meant by aliasing?

Comment: Yes I understand aliasing and the images it creates and that it's a problem with this configuration but reducing the filter bandwidth exacerbates the problem with DC input settling error.

Comment: Then I believe you are justified in taking up this query on the ADI help-site. Personally I don't agree with what is said and, you are not requiring the device to operate at DC anyway.

Comment: Figure 4 and the surrounding text in the datasheet is maybe a clue. Seems that the purpose of the filter we've been discussing is not for aliasing and aliasing should be handled by a separate filter upstream of the driver. The downstream filter is still needed for driver noise however.